# Use javascript selectors without jQuery to select images

Tags: javascript

I have some images like this:

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/test/images/cat01.png" alt="00" class="cat_img">
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/test/images/cat02.png" alt="00" class="cat_img">
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/test/images/cat03.png" alt="00" class="cat_img">
```

and I want to select the image names (cat01.png, cat03.png and cat03.png) with javascript (without jQuery).

How can I do that ?

I have tried :

```
var images = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('cat_img'));
console.log('Images '+images);
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or like this (no need to use Array.prototype.slice)

```
var images = Array.prototype.map.call(
  document.querySelectorAll(".cat_img"),
  function(img) {
    var src = img.src, 
        lastIndex = src.lastIndexOf('/');
    return src.slice(lastIndex + 1);
  });
```

Comment: Like! I would condense the body of the function to just `return img.src.replace(/.+\//, '');` though. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KGwkN/3)

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over your `images` array using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and return the part of the `src` attribute that you want (everything after the last `/`):

```
var images = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('cat_img'));
var imageNames = images.map(function( image ) {
    return image.src.substring( image.src.lastIndexOf("/") + 1 );
} );

console.log(imageNames);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T92Qk/)

Comment: How did this get -1 and the other nearly identical  answer get +3?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example using regex with a loop.

```
var images = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('cat_img'));
for(i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    console.log(images[i].src.replace(/.+\//, ''));
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KGwkN/1)

So to build your array of names, just replace the `console.log(...)` line with `images[i] = images[i].src.replace(/.+\//, '')`